# BASH_VERSION not set and .bashrc not sourced in the interactive shell

Tags: 12.04, source

I created a new user by executing

`sudo useradd -m harry`

When I try to substitute the user by "su - harry" then everything I can see is a "$" (dollar) sign, the autocompletion isn't working and the shell builtins (e.g. source) are not available.

I checked .bashrc and .profile and detected that .bashrc is not getting sourced because $BASH_VERSION is not set.

The code inside .profile looks like follows:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

The command `echo $BASH_VERSION` returns nothing.

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION

$
```

Shell builtins (source .bashrc, . .bashrc) don't work either.

The SHELL variable value was '/bin/sh' which is alias of dash. I changed it to /bin/bash (export SHELL=/bin/bash) but it didn't have any effects.

When I hardcode ". .bashrc" in .profile (of course, just to check if it would work) I receive several errors:

```
admin@host:~$ sudo su - harry
-su: 13: /home/harry/.bashrc: shopt: not found
-su: 21: /home/harry/.bashrc: shopt: not found
-su: 105: /home/harry/.bashrc: shopt: not found
-su: 28: /etc/bash_completion: [[: not found
-su: 34: /etc/bash_completion: [[: not found
-su: 51: /etc/bash_completion: Bad substitution
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w$
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.
jepetko

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This user's shell is `/bin/sh`. This is a smaller shell, which uses fewer resources than bash but offers fewer programming features and next to no interactive features.

Run `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash harry` to change the user's login shell to bash. This changes the user entry in `/etc/passwd` (don't edit that file directly unless you know what you're doing).

Setting the `SHELL` environment variable tells applications to run a different shell but has no effect on the currently running shell.

Comment: htis is actually the right way when the user already exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to create a user with the bash shell by default use this command:

```
useradd -m -s /bin/bash <userName>
```

Replace `<userName>` with the name of the user you wish to create.

Comment: hi Luis, I actually changed the SHELL variable to /bin/bash. okay, lets create a new user... It works!